# embedded controller vs twig extension

Tags: symfony

This is more a discussion question:

Given you have a component in your bundle, that consists of a service, maybe a model and template and you want to give an easy way to include it in your main templates.

You could provide a twig extension which internally uses a helper to render the template like:

```
{{ acme_render_component({foo: 'bar'}) }}
```

or you would decide to let the main template use a embedded controller like:

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeBundle:CoolComponent:render', { 'foo': bar })) }}
```

I guess the cases behave different:
With the twig extension, you would probably use the service first to fill the model and fetch it again in the template.
With the controller you would probably execute the service on demand.

What are the differences, advantages or caveats?
When should you provide the one or the other, or both?

Answer (score 1):

I guess one reason to use a custom Twig extension is performance. A call to "render" in a Twig template is a completely new Request that goes through the whole Symfony lifecycle.

Comment: how do you load, the twig file that will contain the twig extensions if you're not going to use render method within a controller ?